# Why this code cannot set metadata to tif image, but it can set the metadata to jpg?

Tags: c++, jpeg, gdi+, tiff, exif

I have implemented code from this article:

[how to read write metadata using GDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It is working well when saving metadata into jpg, but when I save into tif, I am getting no metadata.

what is the problem and how can I solve it?

This code can add a new metadata to a jpg mage:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
INT main()
{
   // Initialize <tla rid="tla_gdiplus"/>.
   GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
   ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
   GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
   Status stat;
   CLSID  clsid;
   char   propertyValue[] = "Fake Photograph";
   Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(L"FakePhoto.jpg");
   PropertyItem* propertyItem = new PropertyItem;
   // Get the CLSID of the JPEG encoder.
   GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
   propertyItem->id = PropertyTagImageTitle;
   propertyItem->length = 16;  // string length including NULL terminator
   propertyItem->type = PropertyTagTypeASCII; 
   propertyItem->value = propertyValue;
   bitmap->SetPropertyItem(propertyItem);
   stat = bitmap->Save(L"FakePhoto2.jpg", &clsid, NULL);
   if(stat == Ok)
      printf("FakePhoto2.jpg saved successfully.\n");

   delete propertyItem;
   delete bitmap;
   GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
   return 0;
}
```

But this code doesn't work:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
INT main()
{
   // Initialize <tla rid="tla_gdiplus"/>.
   GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
   ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
   GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
   Status stat;
   CLSID  clsid;
   char   propertyValue[] = "Fake Photograph";
   Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(L"FakePhoto.jpg");
   PropertyItem* propertyItem = new PropertyItem;
   // Get the CLSID of the JPEG encoder.
   GetEncoderClsid(L"image/tiff", &clsid);
   propertyItem->id = PropertyTagImageTitle;
   propertyItem->length = 16;  // string length including NULL terminator
   propertyItem->type = PropertyTagTypeASCII; 
   propertyItem->value = propertyValue;
   bitmap->SetPropertyItem(propertyItem);
   stat = bitmap->Save(L"FakePhoto2.tif", &clsid, NULL);
   if(stat == Ok)
      printf("FakePhoto2.jpg saved successfully.\n");

   delete propertyItem;
   delete bitmap;
   GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
   return 0;
}
```

The difference is the decoder and image name. Why it is not working?

Comment: Please provide more details. No one can answer your question unless you show the code that you're using.

Comment: The code is in example on the link that I added to question, but I am going to copy the code here.

Comment: I'm glad you posted your code because the link you provided doesn't show specifically what metadata you're adding. TIFF and JPEG don't necessarily support the same tags and it appears that Microsoft's implementation doesn't properly implement PropertyTagImageTitle when writing TIFF. Maybe you should try using another PropertyTag and see if it's supported for TIFF. BTW - there is no such thing as "ImageTitle" in TIFF tags. See here for a reference: http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/baseline.html

Comment: In fact I am adding GPS data to jpg and it works, but not to tiff. Does tiff support GPS exif metadata?

Comment: There are TIFF GPS tags (http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/gps.html), but Microsoft probably doesn't implement them in TIFF. For this reason and many more, I wrote my own imaging library so that I don't have to hope that Microsoft properly supports a standard.

Comment: @BitBank What Can I do when I don't have that library?

Comment: libtiff is the first thing that comes to mind, but I don't have any direct experience with it.